# Discord Bot command prompt freezes

Tags: discord.js

I don't know why it does this but the after a while or sometimes just as the bot starts up the command prompt window stops updating when I use say console.log when someone sends a message nothing shows up and I then have to press ctrl + c and then everything that had to be logged suddenly gets logged and then the bot works fine again. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could we see some of your code so we know if there is issue there?